# In Spring Security, Can we use nested <intercept-url>?

Tags: spring, security, spring-security

My requirement is as follows:

Suppose there are many urls which comes under "dbservice". for eg 
1. /dbservice/add
2. /dbservice/update
3. /dbservice/remove etc

Hence, for each url I have to write separate line (Considering they have different access level).
So it look like this:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/dbservice/add" access="permitAll"/>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/dbservice/update" access="isAuthenticated"/>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/dbservice/remove" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
```

If the string dbservice gets change then I have to update everywhere which I don't want.

Is there a way where I'll declare dbservice only once and I'll use some variable in detailed url or may be something like this:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/dbservice">
         <security:intercept-url pattern="/add" access="permitAll"/>
         <security:intercept-url pattern="/remove" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
</security:intercept-url>
```

Also consider other tags in http like custom-filter and remember-me.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
   <http pattern="/dbservice/**">
        <intercept-url pattern="/add"  access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/remove" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
   </http>
```

Comment: Hi Boopathi, Thanks for your response but then what about other tags like custom-filters and remember-me service. How they will work?

Comment: just include remember-me and your custom filters inside <http>

Comment: I tried that but it didn't worked. I guess for each section we have to declare remember me explicitly.